# Accidentally deleted branch from TFS - Undelete and Rollback not available?

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2015, branch

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 and have deleted a branch from our TFS source control. Looking at other guides there's mention of being able to recover the branch by opening Source Control Explorer, right-click and select 'Undelete' or 'Rollback'. These options are not available

[image]

I have not got this branch mapped on any workspace. Clicking on 'Undo Pending Changes...' brings up a message saying there are no pending changes. How can I restore a branch on TFS? Is there a way I can enable Undelete or Rollback?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, please make sure you or your teammates **haven't destroyed this branch** (After doing this, there is no way to recover it in TFS server).

### If you delete this branch in Visual Studio,

> ***To restore an item deleted from the server***
>
> From the menu bar choose **Tools, Options**.
>
> On the **Options** dialog box, navigate to **Source Control, Visual
>   Studio Team Foundation Server.**
>
> Select **Show deleted items in the Source Control Explorer**, and then
>   choose **OK**.
>
> From the menu bar choose **View**, **Other Windows, Source Control
>   Explorer.**
>
> In Source Control Explorer, navigate to the folder that contains the
>   item you want to restore.
>
> Open the item’s context menu (select the item and right-click it) and
>   then choose **Undelete**.

### If you delete this branch from your dev machine outside of Visual Studio,

Please check the solution from  MSDN link [Delete or restore files and folders](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/delete-restore-files-folders)

---

Morever, you can also try to use the [undelete command](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/undelete-command) restores items that were previously deleted. For Example:

```
tf undelete [/noget] [/lock:(none|checkin|checkout)] 
[/recursive] itemspec[;deletionID] [/login:username,[password]]
```

---

Update:

***Note:*** To be able to undelete a branch you must first **map the parent folder/branch to your workspace**. Now, the undelete option will be enable.

Comment: Thank you for your answer; I've already been able to show the deleted items on my Source Control Explorer, however when I right-click on my target branch both 'Undelete' and 'Rollback' are greyed out (see screenshot). Is there any way I can re-enable them?

Comment: There's no way to re-enable them if you or your teammates have destroyed them. Usually after  show deleted items, you can directly undelete them. What's the result if you run the undelete command as above mentioned ? Please try to achieve it through command.

Comment: They definitely haven't destroyed the branch; I'll give it a shot with the command

Comment: This was the correct answer however 1 small detail was missing from it; to be able to undelete a branch you must first map the parent folder/branch to your workspace. This now enables the undelete option.

Comment: Thanks for your kindness complement. Have updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer! Very much appreciated :)

Comment: @Patrick-MSFT: the update part of you answer is the actual answer, so maybe that should be made more prominent. Btw. do you know why this is actually required? Technically it should not be needed. It's the same with the delete command, where having to map the folder seem even more strange.

Answer (score 1):

According to the screenshot, there is no workspace configured for it. Try configuring a work space for the project that include the deleted branch to see if the "Undelete" option will be activated.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio go to [Tools->Options] then Select [Source Control->visual Studio Team Founation Server] and check the [Show deleted items in the Source Control explorer].

After that, you can then right click a folder and say "Undelete"

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer though this has already been done, otherwise I wouldn't have been able to show the screenshot in my question :)